# How the scheduled agent in Lotus Domino can run at some specific Hour

Tags: scheduled-tasks, lotusscript

I want my scheduled agent written in Lotusscript run at some specific Hour.
For example,it should be run twice every day, at 8AM and 10PM, etc...
But the Agent Trigger doesn't have the choices.

It just have these four choces below:

```
1.More Than Once a Day:every one hour or every three hour...
2.Daily
3.Weekly
4.Monthly
```

How can i realize the purpose?

Comment: This is on-topic and should not be closed. Scheduling agents is a shared responsibility of developers and administrators in Lotus Notes/Domino environments. (In any case, Super User as suggested by the vote to close is inappropriate. End-users do not schedule agents.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule your agent for every day at 8am.
Create a **second agent** which starts the first agent with

```
       @Command([AgentRun]; "yourFirstAgent")
```

and schedule it for every day at 10pm.

Comment: I used the method before. As I know, many other system doesn't provide the feature just like Lotus Domino.Why? Because of the performance or the trigger limit?

Answer (score 2):

If you choose "More than once a day" you can open the "Schedule.." menu where you can choose to run the agent hourly

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've known the settings. I think I misunderstand something. I will modify the question before.

Answer (score 1):

Just schedule it to run `more than once a day`, then select `run agent every 14 hours` and enable `between times 08:00AM and 10:30PM`